# Verify the connection with MySQL database

Tags: python-3.x, mysql-python

I using MySQLdb for access to mysql database from python. I need to know if connection with database is still alive... are there any attribute or method in order to do this???

thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

To be honest, I haven't used mysqldb in python in a very long time.

That being said, I would suggest using an execute("now()") (or "select 1", any other "dummy" SQL command) and handle any errors.

edit: That should also probably be part of a class you're using.  Don't fill your entire project with .execute("now()") on every other line. ;)